# JExcelAPI reads date fields incorrectly

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

I've been using JExcelAPI to write and read Excel files in Java. It works fine when I read files written by JExcelAPI, but if I modify a .xls file with another program like OpenOffice, JExcelAPI is no longer able to read it properly. For example, a "date" type field with content 04/10/2015 is read as 277/10/2015. I assume this is not an OpenOffice bug, because I can open the file just fine in Google Docs. It looks like a JExcelAPI bug to me. Is there any fix or workaround to this or do I have to replace the entire library?

Answer (score 0):

im not really familiar with jexcelapi but from some reading in their API 
[link to api](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)

its written there that

> Reads data from Excel 95, 97, 2000, XP, and 2003 workbooks

this might be the issue for you , and you most  likely have to pass on this library to other one . 
maybe you will have better luck with [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)

Comment: Yep, I ended up migrating to Apache POI.